# Scroll view does not scroll on first touch

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, all I want is to detect touch on a edit text and scroll the scroll view:

```
View.OnTouchListener buttonFocus = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("TOuch");

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                System.out.println("TOuch down");
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);        
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                System.out.println("TOuch up");                   
                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.m_scroll)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                v.performClick();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

While as the keypad pops up at the start of activity the scroll does not occur, it only scroll when I touch the view for the second time. Am I doing something wrong here? Will implementing a thread help?

Comment: why u need `OnTouchListener`

Comment: I need to scroll views so that a proper picture is presented to the user.

Comment: `ScrollView` scrolls automatically its a default feature of `ScrollView` doesn't have to implement `OnTouchListener` for that

Answer (score 0):

Returning true in that last line of yours might solve your problem.

Returning false means that the onTouch has been used completely and won't entertain any further touch events

Comment: My keypad does not popup, if I return true.

Comment: try searching for other methods to pop up your keyboard, maybe that will help